# Akka Futures + Spring MVC deferred results + tomcat 7.+

Tags: spring, scala, tomcat, spring-mvc

Spring-api 3.+ onwards introduces support aync request processing, So I thought of putting it to sample webapplication with my favourite concurrency model provided by Akka

my code looks something like this

```
      @RequestMapping(value = Array("/"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
      @ResponseBody
      def adminHome(request: HttpServletRequest) : DeferredResult[ModelAndView] = {
  
        import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

        val result = new DeferredResult[ModelAndView]
           
       ........ code for some future .........

      // creating model map future from some future
       val modelMapFuture: Future[Map[String, Any]] = someFuture.flatMap(urlObjects =>
       Future(
        Map("urlList" -> urlObjects.asJava)
       ))


       // setting the deferred result value upon completion of future
        modelMapFuture.onComplete {
          case Success(modelMap) => result.setResult(new ModelAndView("index", modelMap.asJava))
         case Failure(e) => result.setResult(new ModelAndView("index"))
       }

    result
   }
```

I have enable the aync support for Spring mvc DispatcherServelet and all the Filters attached to the url mapping of particular servelet.

But all the time I'm getting an empty page as the result.

I can help you to narrow down the problem by saying -

a. No exception in model/view

If I set view as a simple JSP with hello world, its also not loading.

b. Request mapping is working perfectly

c. Future gets completed without errors

d. Deffered result is set properly

I have bind a DeferredResultProcessingInterceptorAdapter implementation to the mvc:deferred-result-interceptors and put logs for beforeConcurrentHandling, preProcess, postProcess and afterCompletion
I'm getting following logs from the interceptor

> Before concurrent handling request : deffered result  expired or set is  : false
>
> pre process : deffered result  expired or set is  : false
>
> post process :  deffered result  expired or set is  : true
>
> after completion :  deffered result  expired or set is  : true

Any help will be highly appriciated as I was strugging with this for entire two days.

More details

Spring version 3.2.3-RELEASE
Tomcat version 7.0.42

Comment: Minor editing done for, better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using `@ResponseBody` in conjunction with `ModelAndView`. `@ResponseBody` would be used if you were simply returning some data -- something like `DeferredResult[List[String]]`.

Comment: Hi lil mistake from me, I removed the @ResponseBody part still the result is same.